# react reuse feature / component function

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

i'm new to React JS. What is the best practice to apply same function / feature to most page ?

Case : I have Employee, Department, Sallary Menu (component), and i want all of those pages have [injectIntl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API)  feature and react-router prompt feature to prevent user from leaving pages when have update (dirty) form.

For now, i paste the code for each component and when adding new component to my Application. I have tried Higher Order Component, is it possible to call another HOC function from HOC function ? injectIntl is a HOC function. And i want to build my own HOC where it will call injectIntl.

My HOC :

```
import { Component } from "React";
import React from 'react';
import { intlShape, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

export var Enhance = (ComposedComponent) => class EnhanceClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ data: 'Hello' });
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data} />;
    } 

  };

Enhance.propTypes = {
    intl: intlShape.isRequired
};

EnhanceClass = injectIntl(EnhanceClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple HOCs like

```
const EnhancedClass = Enhance(injectIntl(Component));
```

so Your HOC will just look like

```
export var Enhance = (ComposedComponent) => class EnhanceClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ data: 'Hello' });
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data} />;
    } 

  };
```

Now `EnhancedClass` will have the functionality provided by `injectIntl` and `Enhance` HOC both